# Connect mysql database based on route in express.js with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, multi-tenant, saas

I am building Multi tenant application, where each client has separate database.

Is it possible to change the database connection in sequelize depending on the route?

I have two routes

1. scale.com/ss94545
2. scale.com/mn94545

Upon login, users are redirected to scale.com/ss94545, to get all their data for their particular site.

The other mn94545 site uses a separate database and thus if they want to get all their data they have to go to scale.com/mn94545.

Every installation has its own database, and all databases have the same schema.

Is it possible to change the database connection depending on which route is visited?

This my basic static sequelize data connection:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('ss94545', 'root', 'root', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: false,
});
```

Comment: Another way to approach this is to create two sequelize objects at the server start time. Now in your route, you can use the sequelize object which connects to the right db. Hopefully you don't have many dbs. Connecting to db at run time is expensive and would slow down your request.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making the database name a route param and then instantiating sequelize after that?  Assuming you might be using express it would go something like this...

```
app.get('/:dbname', function(req, res) {
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(req.params.dbname, 'root', 'root', {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: false,
  });
  //insert sequelize code here
  res.send('test ' + req.params.dbname);
});
```

Comment: If i do this, i am able to write my table schemas, tables sync inside that function only, i cant able to do outside my function.

Comment: ah, how about instantiating both but with different names.
const db1 = new Sequelize('ss94545', 'root', 'root', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: false,
});
const db2 = new Sequelize('mn94545', 'root', 'root', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: false,
});

Comment: Then, in your ss route, only touch db1.  In your mn route, only touch db2.

Comment: Its SaaS application, so there are chances to have more than 1000 db! so putting static is not makes sense.